# On click of document or window a open div should close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create my custom select drop down using jquery, all goes well except the 
click event on `.select-list`, it should close but currently it's not happening, below one is my code

```
$("#selectedValue").click(function() {
    $(".select-list").toggleClass("showlist");
});
$(".select-list li").click(function() {
    $('#selectedValue').html($(this).text());
    alert($('#selectedValue').text());
    $('.select-list').removeClass("showlist");
})

var selectListClass = $('.select-list').hasClass("showlist");
if (selectListClass) {

    $(document).click(function() {
        $('.select-list').removeClass("showlist");
    });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c7k7nLdu/2/

Comment: Are you still facing problems?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `if` before document click event (just remove it), but `stopPropagation` on the click events. Example:

```
$("#selectedValue").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    ...
```

Here, I updated your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7k7nLdu/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `e.target` inside your `$(document).click(e)` to get the target of the clicked element.

Then use `e.target !== $('#selectedValue')[0]` to check if you have clicked on the "dropdown"

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if (e.target !== $('#selectedValue')[0]) {
    var selectListClass = $('.select-list').hasClass("showlist");
    if (selectListClass) {
      $('.select-list').removeClass("showlist");
    }
  }
});
```

**Example**

```js
$("#selectedValue").click(function() {
  $(".select-list").toggleClass("showlist");
});
$(".select-list li").click(function() {
  $('#selectedValue').html($(this).text());
  alert($('#selectedValue').text());
  $('.select-list').removeClass("showlist");
})

$(document).click(function(e) {
  if (e.target !== $('#selectedValue')[0]) {
    var selectListClass = $('.select-list').hasClass("showlist");
    if (selectListClass) {
      $('.select-list').removeClass("showlist");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#selectDropdown {
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

#selectedValue {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 0;
  background: url("../images/dropdown-arrow.png") no-repeat right;
  line-height: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*     font-size: 13px; */
}

#selectDropdown ul {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#selectDropdown ul.showlist {
  display: block;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}

#selectDropdown ul li {
  line-height: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#selectDropdown ul li:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selectDropdown" class="col-md-4 no-pad">
  <div id="selectedValue" class="col-md-12">Want to add a greeting?</div>
  <ul class="select-list">
    <li>Data sample 1</li>
    <li>Data sample 2</li>
    <li>Data sample 3</li>
    <li>Data sample 4</li>
    <li>Data sample 5</li>
    <li>Data sample 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c7k7nLdu/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        if (e.target.id != 'selectedValue') {
             $('.select-list').removeClass("showlist");
        }
    })
});


$("#selectedValue").click(function(){

  $(".select-list").toggleClass("showlist");
  });
  
  $(".select-list li").click(function(){
    $('#selectedValue').html($(this).text());
    alert($('#selectedValue').text());
    $('.select-list').removeClass("showlist");
})
```

```css
#selectDropdown {
    padding-right: 10px;
    width:200px;
}

#selectedValue {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 0;
    background: url("../images/dropdown-arrow.png") no-repeat right;
    line-height: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#selectDropdown ul { 
  display:none; 
  border:1px solid #f2f2f2;  
  list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; 
}

#selectDropdown ul.showlist {display:block;
 transition-property: all;
 transition-duration: .5s;
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}

#selectDropdown ul li { 
  line-height:24px; cursor:pointer; 
}

#selectDropdown ul li:hover { 
  color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="selectDropdown" class="col-md-4 no-pad">
<div id="selectedValue" class="col-md-12">
  Want to add a greeting?
</div>

  <ul class="select-list">
    <li>Data sample 1</li>
    <li>Data sample 2</li>
    <li>Data sample 3</li>
    <li>Data sample 4</li>
    <li>Data sample 5</li>
    <li>Data sample 6</li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```